# Issue with Exception Handling in Python

Tags: python, exception

I am having following issue with my code in propagating an Exception:

**What the code should do:**

It takes an input for number a of combinations or Test Cases to be run.

It takes n = number and its power = p. (i.e `2^3=8`)

If p and n are positive, it needs to print `2^3 = 8` and return it - this is working.

If either n or p is negative, it needs to print "n and p should be non-negative" - this is not working.

**My code:**

```
class Calculator():
    def power(self,n,p):
        self.n=n
        self.p=p
        try:
            raise NameError("n and p should be non-negative")

        except NameError:
            a=pow(n,p)
            return a
myCalculator=Calculator()
T=int(raw_input())
for i in range(T):
    n,p = map(int, raw_input().split())
    try:
        ans=myCalculator.power(n,p)
        print ans
    except Exception,e:
        print e
```

**Input given**

```
4
3 5
2 4
-1 -2
-1 3
```

**Output received:**

```
243
16
1.0
-1
```

However, I should have received  "n and p should be non-negative" for 3rd and 4th Test Case as last 2 Test Cases(Test Case number 3 and 4) had either of the values set to negative.

What is wrong?

Comment: You're not actually testing for the values to be positive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually checking the values. Do you want something like that?

```
class Calculator():
    def power(self,n,p):
        self.n=n
        self.p=p
        if n<0 or p<0:
            raise NameError("n and p should be non-negative")
        a=pow(n,p)
        return a
```

A `NameError` doesn't make much sense though, replace it with `ValueError`.

Comment: I tried the other way round as well earlier but that didn't worked either , please forgive as i am a new-bee:                                                                                   class Calculator():
    def power(self,n,p):
        self.n=n
        self.p=p
        try:
            if n>0 and p>0:
                a=pow(n,p)
                return a
        except ValueError,e:
            print "n and p should be non negative"    : I will try your code and let you know

Comment: yes you are absolutely right , i figured my mistake and found out what i was doing wrong . Kudos to you